# unique property of 12 and 13?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Using base 10, when 12 is squared and the order reversed, the positive square root is the reverse of the first number. 13 also has this property. What is the name for this property? Are there any integers that also have this property and (clearly) are of more than two digits? (Sorry that I have changed the subject a bit!)

Comment: Do you want to include numbers ending in zero, such as 10?

Comment: They are called [skinny numbers](https://oeis.org/A061909)

Answer (score 1):

This property is referred to as *skinny* (thanks @jjagmath for the [reference](https://oeis.org/A061909)).

There seem to be many numbers with this property, just a few examples (I wrote some code):
1121, 22011, 110102, 130011, 310011.
In total there are 611 such numbers between $10$ and $10^6$ (including ones with trailing zeros).

*Observation*: If $n$ has that property, the reverse of $n$ will have the property too.

*Conjecture*: The digits from any number with this property are exclusively from the set $\{0, 1,2,3\}$. This, and more properties are stated in [reference](https://oeis.org/A061909), albeit without proof

Comment: They are called [skinny numbers](https://oeis.org/A061909)

Comment: Thanks @jjagmath, I have added it to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For a positive integer $n$, define the function $r(n)$ to be the number whose base-10 digits are reversed.  Then consider the function
$$f(n) = r(n^2) - (r(n))^2. \tag{1}$$
Then $n$ meets the conditions stated in your question if and only if $f(n) = 0$.  We will exclude all cases where $n$ is divisible by $10$, as well as cases where $n$ is a palindrome satisfying $f(n) = 0$.

A computer search for all $n \le 10^6$ yields numerous solutions, e.g. $121201$.  However, in all cases, the set of distinct digits of $n$ belong to one of the following:
$$\{0,1\}, \{0,2\}, \{1,2\}, \{1,3\}, \{0,1,2\}, \{0,1,3\}.$$  So for instance, we don't see any $n$ that use digits greater than $3$, and we also don't see any $n$ that use $\{2,3\}$.  I think this could provide some ideas about proving that no such $n$ violating at least one of these two conditions exists.

Comment: The square of a palindromic number does not need to be a palindrome. Hence $f(n) = 0$ does not hold for all palindromic numbers.

Comment: @DominikS Thanks for catching that.  I've revised my response accordingly.

Comment: No worries! I wonder if it might be worth including the palindromes in the result - they do seem to satisfy the same restriction on digits.

Comment: They are called [skinny numbers](https://oeis.org/A061909)

Comment: $(10^n \times a+b)^2=(10^{2n} \times a^2+2 \times 10^n \times a \times b+b^2)$ ; if $a=2$ and $b=3$, $2ab=12$ which is greater than $10$, so it generates problem.